# Плавное изменение размера изображения

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Помогите с маленьким кодом на js.

Есть только два инпута для выбора ширины и высоты без формы и кнопок, а необходимо, чтоб картинка плавно меняла свои размеры, которые будут вводиться в эти инпуты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Наша img:*

```
<img src="images/logo/icon-256.png" class="one"/>
```

**Вариант 1, С JQuery и CSS:**

```
 $(".one").mouseenter(function() {

        $(this).css({
           "-webkit-transition": "all 1s linear",
            "width": "50px",
            "height":"50px"
        });

    }) .mouseleave(function() {

        $(this).css({
            "-webkit-transition": "all 1s linear",
            "width": "256px",
            "height":"256px"
        });

    });
```

С примерами о взаимодействии CSS и JQuery посмотрите [здесь](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

**Вариант 2, без CSS:**

```
// increase factor
var factor = 2;

$('.one').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-=' + $(this).height() / factor,
        left: '-=' + $(this).width() / factor,
        width: $(this).width() * factor
    });
});
```

[Здесь](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) с примерами о animate прочитайте.

**Готовое решение, специально для автора:**

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" size="40" class="width">
 <input type="text" size="40" class="height">

 <img src="images/logo/icon-256.png" class="one" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(".width").keypress(function(){

    $(".one").css({
        "-webkit-transition": "all 1s linear",
        "width":$(this).val(),
        "height": $(".height").val()
    });

});

$(".height").keypress(function(){
    $(".one").css({
        "-webkit-transition": "all 1s linear",
        "width":$(".width").val(),
        "height": $(this).val()
    });
});
```

Я, конечно, все понимаю, но готовые решения приводят к лени, а лень сами знаете к чему, посему советую понемногу изучать все самостоятельно. Да и не напасешься готовых ответов в программировании, даже столь простых штук.

Comment: Может, лучше юзать `.on('keypress', function(){ /* code */ });`?  
Анимация на js себя изживает, css в этом плане куда мощнее стала, да и это прямая обязанность именно css.

Comment: большое спасибо за то, что отозвались, но у меня немного другая ситуация, новые размеры: ширина и высота, задаются вручную через поля input и после того размеры заданы изображение должно менять свои размеры!

Comment: @TheDoctor, автору поста, конечно, надо использовать keypress ибо задумка с моими примерами не пойдет, но их легко переделать под свои нужны, собственно, я и не тостер, чтобы готовое выдавать. :) По поводу изживает или нет - сложный вопрос, но CSS творит последнее время чудеса даже самостоятельно, а с Jquery все очень круто и главное просто.

Comment: @kiberchainik, посмотрите ответ заново, там есть теперь и готовое решение, хоть я и не сторонник токовых для обучающихся, ибо так они ничему не научатся.

Comment: немного не по теме... печатая, когда считаете нужным, готовое решение задачи, не думайте только о лени автора вопроса! Задумайтесь лучше еще о том, как бы подробнее описать свой код в комментариях, ибо многие так учатся в том числе!!!

Comment: @kiberchainik, это не тот случай, когда нужны комментарии. Здесь нет никаких сложных взаимосвязей или вычислений. Да, отметьте, что ли, мой ответ как верный или этого мало?

Comment: нет, все отлично, еще раз большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так (делал для друпала, поэтому jquery обернуть возможно нужно будет по-другому).

html

```
<img src="#" class="one" />
```

jquery

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#edit-submitted-shirina, input').bind('keyUp change', function(){
    var wvalue = $('#edit-submitted-shirina').val();
    $("#bagbox").attr('width', wvalue);
    });

    $('#edit-submitted-vysota, input').bind('keyUp change', function(){
    var hvalue = $('#edit-submitted-vysota').val();
    $("#bagbox").attr('height', hvalue);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```